# Detecting if someone is logged into Meteor from a regular Node.js application

Tags: express, meteor

Is there a way for me to check to see if someone is logged into Meteor from outside of Meteor; for example, from an Express.js application? I would like to know from the Express app who the currently logged in user is on a particular client so that if the API were called, we would know who to apply the results of the API call to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is best done it two parts.

**A method to check whether the user is online in meteor**

You can probably do it with a meteor smart package ([community package repo](http://atmosphere.meteor.com)) : https://github.com/erundook/meteor-profile-online

Make sure you have [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite), installed via `npm install meteorite -g`

In your package repo use : `mrt add profile-online`

**Accessing meteor's data using Express**

To access the stuff in Express you would need a DDP client, I know this one works with pre1 (The version of [DDP with Meteor 0.57+](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/02/22/meteor-057-major-scaling-update-new-ddp-version-ejson)): https://github.com/EventedMind/node-ddp-client

You can have a method that checks for you in meteor

**Server js (Meteor)**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'isonline: function(id) { 
        return Meteor.users.find(id).profile.online;
    }
}
```

**Express:**

```
var client = new DDPClient({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000
});

userid = '1' //The user _id of the person you want to check
client.connect(function () {
   console.log("Connected to Meteor at localhost:3000");
   client.call("isonline", [userid], function(err,result) {
        client.close();
            if(!err) {
                if(result) {
                    console.log("User " + userid + " is online");
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("That user isn't online");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(err)
            }
   });
});
```

Comment: I should have clarified the question more. I want to check if someone is logged into Meteor in the current client from an app outside of Meteor. This Express app wants to check the userId of the currently logged in user in Meteor or null if there isn't one.

Comment: Please could you clarify further I'm a bit lost at logged in the current client from an app outside of Meteor, how would one log in outside of Meteor? Your not inceptioning me right?

Comment: Lets say you are logged in on Meteor. You now would like to perform some tasks on Meteor that require calls to a REST API that is separated from Meteor. However, that REST API server needs to know which user from Meteor is making the requests. How can the REST API know who the user is? Assume the REST API has access to the MongoDB instance that Meteor is accessing as well as the ability to make DDP calls to Meteor.

Comment: Ok so you want to know who the current logged in user is for a particular client? what method are you currently using to identify the client? it should be possible by altering the meteor method abit

Comment: We use Meteor.userID() to figure it out based upon email authentication.

Comment: OK so this needs to be done at the where the REST requests originate, I assume you're doing the REST requests to your express server? you could also pass along `Meteor.userId()` and use this to with the above to check if the user is logged in

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26185/discussion-between-hiravgandhi-and-akshat)